# Why is Google maps (the built-in app) so slow on the iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

My Google Maps app for iOS has gotten too slow to be useful at times.  It doesn't seem to be a bandwidth issue, as it even affects typing- there's often meaningful lag from when i type a letter until it appears.

I've tried a full restart.    Any ideas?

Comment: its not your phone. its a problem with google maps, as many other people have been experiencing the same problem. it must be from a recent update.

Answer (score 5):

From a [MacRumors.com forum post](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-957373.html#copyright):

> **My problem**: Typing on the Google Maps app was very slow, independent of network connection.
>
> **My solution**: Apparently there are issues with the GPS multitasking. I went to Settings > General > Location Services. Notice you can toggle the GPS for each app. Apps using the GPS have a purple arrow next to the ON/OFF switch. I turned location services off for every other app with the purple arrow. I went back to the Google Maps application and everything worked well.
>
> This might not work for everyone but it worked for me.

Comment: Worked very well for me.  Went from having to wait literally minutes for the search field to respond to keyboard events to just a few seconds.  Also clearing google maps search 'recents' seemed to add additional improvement.

Comment: That's odd. The location icon on the settings screen only denotes that the app has used your location in the last 24 hours. It does not (necessarily) mean it has a standing location update. Though that might be the case with apps such as Google Latitude. Regardless it's not necessarily noted by the icon alone. This probably means also that if you double clicked the home button and killed all apps in the multitasking menu that your input speed would improve too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. None of the suggested fixes worked. I deleted the app from my phone, then reloaded it. When asked about the app tracking my location, I opted for "Always" and the app has worked fine ever since.